# JS alter element with certain id and class name

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the style of a div with vanilla JS. The div should have a certain id and the class name `tab-content`:

```
function showTabContent() {
    document.getElementById(tabID).classList.contains("tab-content").style.display = "block";
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="1" class="tab-content">Test...</div>
<div id="2" class="tab-content">Test...</div>
<div id="3" class="tab-content">Test...</div>
```

If for example I run:

```
showTabContent(2);
```

It should set the `tab-content` div with id `2` to style display block. It is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `.classList.contains("tab-content")` returns a boolean value, not an object with a `style` property. Just omit that part, use `document.getElementById(tabID).style.display = "block";` - the id does already uniquely identify your element, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should pass tabID to your function.

.containe() method in JavaScript shows whether a string has a specific word or letter and if the condition is true, it will return `true`. (boolean)
if you want to get the element with a specific ID and `tab-content` class, you can work with `querySelector`.

```
document.querySelector("#"+tabID+".tab-content").style.display="block"
```

But since ID is most often unique, referring to the ID alone is sufficient.

```
document.getElementById(tabID).style.display="block"
```

Comment: This does not work. I get `Uncaught TypeError: document.getQuerySelector is not a function`. I think you are using incorrect code.

Comment: That was a mistake. sorry. That's `querySelector`

Answer (score 0):

is the code pasted is right from the source code.

The above function `showTabContent()` should accept argument.
`showTabContent(tabId)`

Comment: Similar answers have already been given.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing the `id` to function `showTabContent` then you can receive it using parameter i.e `tabId`.

then you have to find the element and check for its existence. It could be possible that the element with specified `id` is not present.

```js
function showTabContent(tabId) {
  const element = document.getElementById(tabId);
  if (element) {
    element.style.display = "block";
    element.style.backgroundColor = "lime"; // FOR VISUAL PURPOSE ONLY
  }
}

showTabContent(2);
```

```html
<div id="1" class="tab-content">Test...</div>
<div id="2" class="tab-content">Test...</div>
<div id="3" class="tab-content">Test...</div>
```